# How do you use &nbsp; in GWT UiBinder XML? Can you escape it?

Tags: gwt, escaping, uibinder

In my mark-up I want to add a space (&nbsp;) between elements without always having to use CSS to do so. If I put &nbsp; in my markup, GWT throws errors. Is there a way around it?

For example:

```
<g:Label>One&nbsp;</g:Label><g:Label>Two</g:Label>
```

Should show:

```
One Two
```

And not:

```
OneTwo
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As documented [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#HTML_entities), you just have to add this to the top of your XML file and it will work!

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
```

Note that the GWT compiler won't actually visit this URL to fetch the file, because a copy of it is baked into the compiler. However, your IDE may fetch it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a Label, which to me shouldn't allow character entities at all, I use an HTML widget.  In order to set the content, though, I find I have to do it as the HTML attribute, not the body content (note that the uppercase HTML is important here, since the set method is setHTML, not setHtml)

```
<g:HTML HTML="One&amp;nbsp;" />
```